Tailwind CSS responsive stepper
This is the goal:

This is what I've achieved so far:

But I don't understand if there's a way to justify-content: flex-start; the after pseudo element (the connecting line)
This is the code I currently have:
<div id="reservas" class="bg-black p-20">
  <div class="bg-black/70 h-full w-full">
    <ol class="flex items-center w-full text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-base md:px-80">
      <!-- Item -->
      <li class="flex md:w-full items-center align-items-start text-blue-600 bg-green-500 dark:text-blue-500 sm:after:content-[''] after:w-full after:h-1 after:border-b after:border-gray-200 after:border-1 after:hidden sm:after:inline-block after:mx-6 xl:after:mx-10 dark:after:border-gray-700">
        <div class="flex align-items-start after:content-['/'] align- bg-green-500 sm:after:hidden after:mx-2 after:text-gray-200 dark:after:text-gray-500">
          <div class="flex-col items-center">
            <img src="/dist/assets/icons/click.png" alt="" class="bg-yellow-400 w-16" />
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- End Item -->
       ... More items ...
      <!-- Last item. different than the others -->
      <li class="flex items-center">
        <div class="flex-col items-center">
          <img src="/dist/assets/icons/click.png" alt="" class="bg-yellow-400 w-16" />
          <h4>title</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- End Item -->
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>


